# How to protect your web application's data against an injected JavaScript?

Tags: web-application, web-browser, javascript, browser-extensions

I have a web application which interacts with two web servers. The response of the first one is stored temporarily on the browser (window.xyz=response.xyz) and when the user makes the request for second server, we send this data along as one of the parameters.

Now this is not secure as if someone has a malicious browser extension installed on the browser, it can inject the javascript and expose the variables.

What would be a good way to protect against such possibilities? I have a feeling that there is some pretty simple solution that the developers have not thought of. Can using local variables passed as parameters to other functions work instead? I am not acquainted with Javascript.

Further context: I am mainly interested in ensuring that the malicious script can't expose the variables and use them to fake requests

Comment: What sort of data are you storing in the browser?  What level of control do you have over the servers?  Do you own both of them?  Do are you able to update the code for both applications?  If you are able to update the code on both servers, is there any reason you can't just push the data from server A to server B?

Comment: The data that is being stored is something like a session token A. I control server B and not A. So enforcing A to send data directly to B is not possible. B uses A's API to ensure that the data sent by the browser is valid

Comment: So if I understand your comment about the API correctly, A => Browser, Browser => B, B => A to confirm the data.  Is that correct?

Comment: @user52472 yes that is correct

Comment: I don't understand your threat model at this point.  If B is currently validating that the data the user submitted is valid, what are you trying to defend against?

Comment: @user52472 So my main worry is some malicious javascript reading the data that I am storing in the window.xyz variable. This information can be used to either make fake requests or to just gather information for further attacks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to transfer information from server A to server B through the users browser, but you don't want to trust the browser since there might be a malicious extension or similar which modifies the data inside the browser before sending it to B.

I don't think that there is anything at the client side which makes thus modification impossible, i.e. you cannot trust the browser in any way. Thus, if you really insist on transferring the data using the browser you must have some other way to make sure that nobody has tampered with the data, i.e. something you can really trust instead of the browser.

My choice would be that you should trust server A, because you already need to trust A anyway since this is the source of the data. Thus you have to make sure that the data did really originate at server A. The typical way to do this is to use digital signatures: server A has a key pair, server B knows the public key, server A signs the data with its private key and server B can validate these with the public key. Another option would be to have a shared secret between A and B and use this inside a HMAC.

This way any manipulation of the data will be detected, no matter where on the way between A and B these manipulation occur.

Comment: So the data that is stored on the client side is something like a session token. The session token is validated on server B to ensure that it is still valid and a correct session token (server A has an API for this). I am worried that if somebody else hijacks this session token, they may be able to use it for some other purpose.

Comment: @Limit: This is actually a different scenario  then you describe in your question. But, if you want to make sure that a token can only be used for a specific purpose than you need to verify at the web application (i.e. server side) that the received token is allowed to be used for this purpose. If this is properly done it cannot be used for a different purpose.

Comment: To be absolutely clear. I am mostly worried about some javascript reading the window.xyz variable and if I can stop it or not. If not, I will look into ways where I can handle this exposure

Comment: I already have CORS protection in place for the session token

Comment: @Limit: every script which is included has access to the same Javascript resources, i.e. you cannot protect script from site A against script from site B if both are included into the same page. CORS does not matter here  since this is only about accessing external resources  and not about the actions successfully included resources can do within the site.

Comment: fair point. Last question: Do web applications which use a third party identity provider not have to worry about this?

Comment: @Limit: first, this is a new question and should not be asked in a comment. Second - this is far too broad. It is possible that specific applications with a specific task and using a specific identity provider don't have this problem but I would not argue that just by using a third party identity provider the apps get magically secure against security problems caused by a browser which cannot be trusted.

Answer (score 1):

What you are really asking is how do you limit the impact of an XSS attack.  Unfortunately, given your scenario, there's not much you can do, since the token must be accessed in JavaScript to get it from Server A. Your best bet would be to implement a strong content security policy (CSP).  CORS does not apply to this scenario.

I'm not too familiar with how CSP applies to plugins, but I don't think there is anything that can be done to protect against a malicious plugin.

Comment: To clarify on the last part: CSP is not intended to limit plugins/extensions, so browsers generally let plugins/extensions bypass it.

Answer (score 1):

JS uses a reference-based security model, so if your extension cannot get a reference to the secret, it cannot access the secret. Unless the extension controls (and over-rides) the loading of page scripts, a script can be constructed to share secrets in a way pre-run or post-run code cannot directly interfere with.

The hard part is authenticating the needy part because a naive getSecret() is little safer than window.secret=blah. Introduce the two parts, let them self-ref without public variables, and then seal off further references. This will let you connect the two pieces in such a way that can be severed, but not tapped or spoofed.

```
// this part contains a secret only specific other code should see:
var hasSecret=(function(){ 
 var mySecretRef; // an object refrence, to be populated at run-time
 var mySecretData = ["I like anchovies"]; // in array so it can be updated later
 var out={};
 out.meet=function(obj){
    mySecretRef = obj;  // bake-in a specific object
    delete out.meet; // burn this bridge
    // define a method that can only use the non-replaceable baked-ins:
    out.reveal= mySecretRef.obtain.bind(mySecretRef, mySecretData); 
    Object.freeze(out); // just for easier debugging on attempts under global "use strict"
 };

 return out;
}());


// this code needs a secret that no other code should see and only one part has (the above)
var getSecret={ 
 obtain: function(secret){
   prompt("The Secret Is", secret || "N/A"); // (instead of demo prompt(), custom app-logic goes here)
 }
};


// kick the tires a little bit:
hasSecret.meet(getSecret); // bake-in object relationship, the prime "feature" of this pattern
hasSecret.reveal = Boolean; // attack:  try to over-ride reveal()
getSecret.obtain(); // attack: obtain() can be manually called, but has no secret data
hasSecret.reveal() // legit: shows "I like anchovies" (the secret) by calling getSecret.obtain() callback
getSecret.obtain = function(secret){ return "This is a fake secret";}; // attack: try to over-ride obtain()
hasSecret.reveal() // legit: shows "I like anchovies" still, as desired
hasSecret.meet({}); // attack: remeet (throws error since meet() is gone
```

Of course, this could be putting a bank vault door on a tent if the XMLHttpRequest object is tampered with, the page's scripts are replaced outright with an extension, or if either server is not HTTPS. In short, while the revealing module pattern itself should be bullet-proof, the application of the pattern might not be.

EDIT:Make sure that you don't hard-code the secret data into the source code, but rather fetch the data, set *mySecretData*, and then immediately call `meet()`.

Comment: "Make sure that you don't hard-code the secret data into the source code, but rather fetch the data" A script injected on the domain or a browser extension could fetch the data in the same way that the page code does. Also, besides that XMLHttpRequest could easily be overridden by an injected script or extension, so could any global such as `Function.prototype.bind` or `Object.freeze`, which provide more ways to leak the secret in your example.

Comment: @AgentME: you could get new refs to `window.Object` or ajax from a dynamic iframe or worker, but you're right about the ever-deep rabbit hole i alluded to. a server can only give the secret once, so as long as a script beats the attacker's, that part's ok, or at least file-able under "validate all input" on the server.

Comment: The global functions used for creating/retrieving the iframe (document.createElement, document.querySelector, etc) could be substituted out so they patch the variables in iframes before they're returned. (Or the extension could be set up so it injects its patching code in iframes too.) Then XMLHttpRequest/fetch could be replaced so the initial secrets retrieval is intercepted. The extension can run code in the page to manipulate globals before the page javascript can do anything.